# How do i make Xpath search case insensitive

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm currently making a xpath search, I've got the the search working but I need to make it case insensitive. The xml file I'm using is 1.0 which from my research means I've got to use some thing called a translate function but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Here is my search file :

```
$holidayDoc = simplexml_load_file('holidays.xml');      

// fetch data from form
$txtSearch = $_GET['txtSearch'];

$qry = "//channel/item[contains(.,\"$txtSearch\")]";


$holidays = $holidayDoc->xpath($qry);   // do the xpath query 
// now loop through all the students

echo "Showing title search results for $txtSearch";

foreach ($holidays as $holiday) 
{

 echo "<p><a href=\"{$holiday->link}\">{$holiday->title}</a></p>
    <p><small>$holiday->pubDate</small></p>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: @alain.janinm: The currently-accepted answer is incorrect -- see my answer for explanation and for the correct XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0 expressions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

XPath 1.0 :

```
$qry = "//channel/item[contains(
 translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),  
 translate($search, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]"
```

XPath 2.0 :

```
$qry = "//channel/item[lower-case(.) = lower-case($search)]"
```

Both replace all upper case to lower case.

Answer (score 4):

**The currently accepted answer is flawed -- because nothing guarantees that the second argument of `contains()` is already converted to lower case**.

Also, it uses `'$search'` -- and this is literally the string `"$search"` -- not the *variable* `$search`.

**Here is a correct solution**:

```
//channel/item
   [contains(translate(., 
                       'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                       'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
             translate($txtSearch, 
                       'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                       'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
             )
   ]
```

**The corresponding XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
//channel/item[contains(lower-case(.), lower-case($txtSearch))]
```

**Update**:

Based on this solution, `@alain.janinm` has corrected his answer.

Comment: +1 you're right I've thought the second part was always in lower case.

Comment: it's a bit silly to do the translate() on the $txtSearch, when you can simply pass strtolower($txtSearch)...

Comment: @MladenB. Please, do note that the OP's question is for a **pure XPath 1.0 expression**. In XPath 2.0 one can use the standard XPath 2.0 function `lower-case()` as specified in my answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, I understand what OP asked for, but your answer has an extra part that's really not needed in his case. If "$txtSearch" is a parameter to the xpath expression, then you have control over it, outside of the XPath (in this case, php). So, you can lowercase it before you perform your xpath expression.

Comment: @MladenB. Please, if you insist on bringing this question **out of context** then you could use even Assembler for lower-casing. The value of this and the other answers is that they focus on the question at hand and provide the requested by the OP information.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, to do a case-blind comparison you should use a case-blind collation, unless your text happens to be English; normalizing both operands to upper case or to lower case does not give the correct result in all circumstances. Unfortunately collation names (in XPath 2.0) aren't standardised so you have to look in your product documentation to see what collations are available.

Answer (score 1):

A case insensitive search can be using using the `matches` function like so

```
$qry = "//string[text() [matches(.,'^stringImTryingToFind$','i')]]"
```

the `//string[text() [matches(.,'^OK$','i')]]` section of the query uses regular expressions (REGEX) to determine a match.