# XML XPath ignore Case and Whitespace

Tags: xml, xpath, php

I have done searching and still don't have a clear view with this.

 I got XML that is save in my local xml.xml

```
<ITEM NAME='Sample'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >
<ITEM NAME='SamPlE lorem'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >
<ITEM  NAME='Sam Ple lorem ipsum'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >
<ITEM  NAME='sample'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >
<ITEM  NAME='SAMPLE'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >

$xmlfile = 'localhost/project/xml.xml'
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
```

I need to search this string `"sample"` ignoring the case sensitivity and the white space so that I may get `TRUE` on every node of above xml, all I have so far is this

```
 //ITEM is not a parent node thats why I am using this line 
 //to lead me to certain part of my xml
 //that match my contain search

 $string = "sample";
 $result = $xml->xpath("//ITEM[contains(@NAME, '$string')");
```

but I got the result of

```
<ITEM  NAME='sample'>
   ..some other node here
</ITEM >
```

I also try the translate function said in this [How do i make Xpath search case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266210/how-do-i-make-xpath-search-case-insensitive) but I always got an error.

Comment: try setting xml:space='preserve' on the root element of your document.

Comment: @Orangepill if I do that does it alter my entire xml ? does xml:space='preserve' put this "sam ple" to "sample"? thanks for idea sir.

Comment: no unfortunately it won't collapse the space for you... sorry

Comment: @Orangepill yeah I have read the manual you right it wont, maybe there is no function for that, only translate() turning the " " to "". but every-time I use that translate() error comes, dunno how to code that rightfully.

Comment: You may enhance your XPATH with //ITEM[contains(normalize-space(lower-case(@NAME)), 'sample')] to avoid cases

Comment: @NavinRawat I see thanks for that sir, but what is your say to the collapse whitespace? it is posible?

Comment: If you get an error, you should document which one and with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML's Xpath is not very fitting to do the whole job. Especially case-insensitivity search is pretty akward - and you are actually confronted with too much [in the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266210/how-do-i-make-xpath-search-case-insensitive).

One way to simplify the job is to divide it. E.g. first get the list of all interesting elements/attributes, then filter them and then get all their parent elements.

This can be easily done by turning the xpath result (which is an array) into an [`Iterator`](http://php.net/class.iterator)

```
$string   = "sample";
$names    = $xml->xpath('//ITEM/@NAME');
$filtered = new LaxStringFilterIterator($names, $string);
$items    = new SimpleXMLParentNodesIterator($filtered);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

This then will output the searched nodes (exemplary):

```
<ITEM NAME="Sample">
   ..some other node here
</ITEM>
<ITEM NAME="SamPlE lorem">
   ..some other node here
</ITEM>
<ITEM NAME="Sam Ple lorem ipsum">
   ..some other node here
</ITEM>
<ITEM NAME="sample">
   ..some other node here
</ITEM>
<ITEM NAME="SAMPLE">
   ..some other node here
</ITEM>
```

And the separated solution for the filtering the array based on the string value:

```
/**
 * Class LaxStringFilterIterator
 *
 * Search for needle in case-insensitive manner on a subject
 * with spaces removed.
 */
class LaxStringFilterIterator extends FilterIterator
{
    private $quoted;

    /**
     * @param Traversable|Array|Object $it
     * @param string $needle
     */
    public function __construct($it, $needle) {
        parent::__construct($it instanceof Traversable ? new IteratorIterator($it) : new ArrayIterator($it));
        $this->quoted = preg_quote($needle);
    }

    public function accept() {
        $pattern = sprintf('/%s/i', $this->quoted);
        $subject = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', trim(parent::current()));
        return preg_match($pattern, $subject);
    }
}
```

And the parent nodes decorator:

```
/**
 * Class SimpleXMLParentNodesIterator
 *
 * Return parent nodes instead of current SimpleXMLElement Nodes,
 * for example the element of an attribute.
 */
class SimpleXMLParentNodesIterator extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function current() {
        $current = parent::current();
        list($parent) = $current[0]->xpath('..');
        return $parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to MVC coding for php, I am having problem where to put that classes since I have main class, but soon it fix I will update you..Thanks for big help.

Comment: This is not particularly MVC related, I suggest you to create a library folder where you can put in all your classes and then create some kind of auto-loader. That's normally pretty light-weight.

Comment: ah yea great suggestion. I forgot that one.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get every @Name which starts-with 'sample' without taking care of cases and space between, you must use :

```
//ITEM[matches(normalize-space(@NAME), '^[sS]\s?[aA]\s?[mM]\s?[pP]\s?[lL]\s?[eE]')]
```

output: all items

Comment: really? including this <ITEM  NAME='Sam Ple lorem ipsum'>  ? and could I ask how this ^[sS]\s?[aA]\s?[mM]\s?[pP]\s?[lL]\s?[eE] works?Thanks

Comment: Yes, it would take care everthing like 's a m p l e', 'SA m P L e', or whatever combination. [sS] we are checking that it must be any character from 's' or 'S' and by '\s?' we are checking space which may or may not present.

Comment: I more thing sir, you says in above code that as long as "sample" is in start. What if I have node like <ITEM  NAME='lorem ipsum SaM ple'> what would be our treatment? will it be enlist in output? BIG Thanks!

Comment: If you want to check 'sample' anywhere in @name use //ITEM[matches(normalize-space(@NAME), '[sS]\s?[aA]\s?[mM]\s?[pP]\s?[lL]\s?[eE]')] where we have remove '^' which was checking starting string only. You may also look http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_matches.html to get some understanding.

Comment: This is hardly an answer at all, there is no such function *matches*  in PHP xpath: *"Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found"* - The OP must have accepted it in error.

Comment: In PHP you have preg_match. Check http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#1. But for XPATH my answer is OK

Comment: @NavinRawat: No, the answer is not OK for Xpath in PHP because PHP does not support Xpath 2.0. Your answer is Xpath 2.0. Otherwise OP should rewrite the question.

Comment: @hakre what would be my solution? right now I just finish my whole function assuming I got all that node. I have not test the above code.

Comment: @kodewrecker: I added an answer in the hope it shows you a different way to solve the problem.